# email hyperlinkbutton

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink, mailto

I'm trying to use a hyperlink button as a mailto in silverlight 4 like so:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="hlbCustomerSupport" NavigateUri="mailto:customerservice@fofo.com" Content="customerservice@fofo.com"></HyperlinkButton>
```

and when I click it in the application I get:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Wed, 19 Jan 2011
>   14:24:29 UTC
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight Application  Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError
>   Message: System.ArgumentException:
>   Content for the URI cannot be loaded.
>   The URI may be invalid. Parameter
>   name: uri    at
>   System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.NavigateCore(Uri
>   uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean
>   suppressJournalAdd, Boolean
>   isRedirect)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Uri
>   source)    at
>   MS.Internal.NavigationHelper.TryInternalNavigate()
>   at
>   MS.Internal.NavigationHelper.Navigate(Boolean
>   checkUserInitiatedAction)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.OnClick()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control
>   ctrl, EventArgs e)    at
>   MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr
>   unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs,
>   Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)

I do this programatically elsewhere and it works.  I tried the same approach for this one and still get the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out.  The hyperlinkButton that works is in a child window (far nested control), the one that doesn't is in the site template (Child of the Application object).  For this reason it appears that the hyperlinkbutton in the site template must have TargetName="_blank" specified.  Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the error by adding a click event to the xaml and storing the url in the Tag="" property.

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="PDR Drug Handbook" Tag="http://www.pdrhealth.com/" FontSize="14" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperlinkButton button = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
        System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(button.Tag.ToString()), "_self");
    }
```

- http://forums.silverlight.net/t/245500.aspx/1

EDIT: popup blockers are now less likely to be invoked due to changing the target from "_blank" to "_self"

Comment: From what I have seen any method other than via the NavigateUri seems to be blocked by pop up blockers. If you are looking at multi browser support this is not an option.

Comment: That's a good point, I didn't think about popup blockers. I changed the hyperlink target to "_self" with popup blockers in mind. As the target doesn't matter for a mailto: