# Creating a mailto: hyperlink in Silverlight Out Of Browser app

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to create a mailto: hyperlink in a Silverlight 4 OOB app?  Thanks!

Edit: based on some of the discussion, an acceptable answer would be a different way than using the HyperlinkButton, or a way to use the HyperlinkButton without having the extra popup in IE.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. If you give some more context we can help you more (i.e.: post some code).

Comment: I need to emulate a mailto hyperlink with a given email address.  Not sure what more info is needed.

Comment: ok... you've seen/heard of the `HyperlinkButton` control I take it?

Comment: Yes, and I have NavigateUri="mailto:tips@silverlighttips.com" set and I get an error when using it: "Content for the URI cannot be loaded. The URI may be invalid."

Comment: See, that's the sort of context I was talking about.

Comment: Per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736358/email-hyperlinkbutton/4737750#4737750), it looks like you need to set the `TargetName` property to `_blank`

Comment: Doing that, it does open a new email message, but it also opens a new browser window with the URL of mailto:tips@silverlighttips.com and a message of "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally it would have been nice of you to post some code, as I have no idea whether the email address is known/determined at design-time or run-time, but nonetheless:

In XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="mailButton" NavigateUri="mailto:somedude@example.com" TargetName="_blank"></HyperlinkButton>
```

In C#:

```
HyperlinkButton hbtn = new HyperlinkButton();
hbtn.Name = "mailButton";
hbtn.TargetName = "_blank";
hbtn.NavigateUri = new Uri("mailto:somedude@example.com"); 
parent.Controls.Add(hbtn);
```

In a situation in which you don't know the email address at design time, it's relatively straightforward to assign the value of the `NavigateUri` property within a method.

Comment: I've tried the following: <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding ContactEmail}" NavigateUri="mailto:tips@silverlighttips.com" /> and I get an error when using it: "Content for the URI cannot be loaded. The URI may be invalid."

Comment: I also tried with including TargetName="_blank" and it does open a new email message, but it also opens a new browser window with the URL of mailto:tips@silverlighttips.com and a message of "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" in IE.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try playing with different values for `TargetName` to see if you get a different result?

Comment: I'll check it out, and if I find it I'll post it.  I verified the same behavior on a different machine in a different project.

Comment: FWIW I've always found Silverlight OOB to be kind of a beast in terms of odd side effects like the IE window opening that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a solution to this issue on CodeProject
http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/383879/Silverlight-mailto-HyperlinkButton-always-opens-an#answer2

Essentially, instead of using the default behaviour add a click event and then call javascript location.href. This stops the extra browser window opening.

```
private void TestLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Only run the click event if in browser because this will not work OOB
     if (Application.Current.IsRunningOutOfBrowser)
         return;

     var cmd = String.Format("location.href='mailto:test@test.com?subject=blah&body=something';",

     HtmlPage.Window.Eval(cmd);
}
```