# Content for the URI cannot be loaded. The URI may be invalid

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, silverlight-5.0

I must say I am pretty stumped by this and I hope some of you have perhaps encountered the same issue. I have a HyperlinkButton, created like this:

```
var hb = new HyperlinkButton
{
     Content = fooText,
     ClickMode = ClickMode.Release,
     NavigateUri = new Uri(fooLink.Value)
};
hb.Click += hb_Click;

static void hb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
    HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(btn.NavigateUri, "_blank");
}
```

The link is an absolute URL to a website (http://...), not inside the application. Therefore, I want to open it in a new browser tab. Which is exactly what it does! The website opens in a new tab, but in the application tab I get this error:

[image]

If I change the event handler so that there's no target parameter, like this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(btn.NavigateUri);
```

...the error appears as well, just before the browser navigates away from the application. But I want to open a new tab.

I am using the Silverlight Business Application template from Visual Studio 11 and I've already noticed it has a few mystery bugs, this might be one of them. All in all, it works, I just need to get rid of the error message. But there is no exception thrown in the event handler that I could swallow.

Comment: Please copy/paste error's stack trace in text, screenshot makes no sense.

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll try to remember it next time. I thought it might help to post the whole thing, instead of just the Error Details thingy. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: In case the image ever became unaccessible, here it is in text & translated to English (for some reason, the original message is "bilingual"):

Error
Content for the URI cannot be loaded. The URI may be invalid.
Parameter name: uri

Error Details
   in System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.NavigateCore(Uri uri, NavigationMode mode, Boolean suppressJournalAdd, Boolean isRedirect)

Comment: Images is hosted on special dedicated to SO service, so it will be kept for pretty long time.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736358/email-hyperlinkbutton and similar?

Comment: Translation is introduced by .NET Language Pack installed in your system. I'd recommend to remove it to have error texts in English what is easy to search for.

Comment: I have searched for the english part only, of course. I have found this: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/205963.aspx/1 but they use something in XAML, I can't do that here (not to mention I don't understand what they did there).

Comment: Why are you using an HyperlinkButton if you use an event handler to navigate?

Comment: @jv42 Because I want to open a new tab. But you are onto something here, mister! If I remove the event handler, I only get the error message. That means the standard event handler is somehow mangled and I need to put it out of its misery so that clicking only triggers my event handler. But how?

Comment: If you want to open a new tab, you just have to setup the target to be "_blank".

Comment: BTW, I've had severe issues with trying to do this like you are, some CMS blocked the navigation if not using the NavigationButton built it feature.

Comment: From what I have seen any method other than via the NavigateUri seems to be blocked by pop up blockers. If you are looking at multi browser support the solution suggested in the UPDATE above seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do just this:

```
var hb = new HyperlinkButton
{
     Content = fooText,
     ClickMode = ClickMode.Release,
     NavigateUri = new Uri(fooLink.Value),
     TargetName = "_blank"
};
```

without the Click event handler.

It should do exactly what you want, in a cleaner way too.

Comment: Yes, thank you!
I don't know why it works, but it works. Upon setting the TargetName property, the error does no longer show.

Comment: As I said on a comment to the question, I've encountered this kind of issue (cannot navigate programmatically) on some unknown CMS on a client deployment. Switching to the native HyperlinkButton functionality fixed the issue, after many unsuccessful fix attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Hyperlink button - simulates hyperlink click
    /// </summary>
    private class HyperlinkButtonWrapper : HyperlinkButton
    {
        public void OpenURL(string navigateUri)
        {
            OpenURL(new Uri(navigateUri, UriKind.Absolute));
        }

        public void OpenURL(Uri navigateUri)
        {
            base.NavigateUri = navigateUri;
            base.TargetName = "_blank";
            base.OnClick();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method opens url
    /// <para>Example: OpenURL("http://www.google.com")</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="navigateUri"></param>
    public static void OpenURL(string navigateUri)
    {
        new HyperlinkButtonWrapper().OpenURL(navigateUri);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Thanks anyway.